# How can I configure Django setup to not need sudo?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, sudo

I have `pip`, `virtualenv`, and `django` installed globally. Using py3, default is set using alias line in `~./bash_profile` - so py2 packaged with Mac still there.

In new `virtualenv`, activated, but when I try to do anything with `django` get following error:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

If I run with sudo (i.e. `sudo python manage.py migrate`) command works.

I know problem is likely how I installed `pip`, but anyway to fix this without re-installing everything?

Comment: Housekeeping question: have you installed django in your virtualenv?  You need to install it separately, so if you haven't that could be the issue.  IE `activate my-virtual-env` then `pip install django`

Comment: Yes - installed in virtualenv

Comment: Hmm...so if you run `pip list` you get what?

Comment: pip list: Django (1.9.6)
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
wheel (0.29.0) -- inside the venv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen for several different reasons (from most basic to more complicated):

1. Django not installed, either globally, in your virtualenv, or both. Check using `pip list`. Most of the time `pip install django` will fix. Do not `sudo` this, or you will have to `sudo` everything. Also: double check django version matches python version; `pip install --upgrade django` to get latest version.
2. Virtualenv not activated - use `source your_path/venv/bin/activate`
3. Mac users - running python3 on virtualenv, but python2.7 default on comp. Fix by deactivating first virtualenv, manually deleting bin||venv, start new virtualenv set to use python2.7. Use `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 env`.
4. Similar - server running different versions. Sometimes you can fix with alias (ala `alias python=python2.7`), but make sure to only use on instance being used for project, not on local comp. Local comp wont work, because sudo being run for default python version regardless.
5. In `manage.py` defaulted path not correct. This depends on your setup and where python dependencies stored. If this is your problem, replace shebang with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Be careful re: python versions here, so if issue with OS default different from using, just add number to end of python (ex: `python3`).
6. Follow @antonis answer, figure out where in `$PYTHONPATH` not matching up with sudo PATH. Pipe/update profile to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `python manage.py migrate`, simply tell it `python`. It will start an interactive python interpreter. Tell it the following:

```
import sys
sys.executable
sys.path
```

`sys.executable` is the full pathname of the Python executable. It should be something inside your virtualenv. `sys.path` is the list of directories in which Python searches for modules whenever you try to `import` something. This should include your virtualenv.

Now exit Python and tell it `sudo python`. Enter the same directives. What are the differences?

This should give you a hint on what you've done wrong and you should be able to debug it further.

You might also find my article, [virtualenv demystified](http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/), useful.